# which market instruments are used to strip the SOFR curve under 1 year?

Tags: yield-curve, sofr, risk-free-rate, stripping

which instruments are used to strip the SOFR curve for the short term of the curve(below 1 y) ?
there are no swaps with maturity under 1 year, right?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The trading is being more and more active on 1-month and 3-month SOFR Futures.
These quotes should help bridging with liquid swap quotes on mid-term maturities and stripping the appropriate curve.

https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/interest-rates/secured-overnight-financing-rate-futures.html